# How to let Gulp wait on SSH before proceeding

Tags: ssh, scp, gulp

I'm trying to delete files on a server with SSH, before copying new versions with SCP. The filenames include a hash for cache busting, so the old files have to go first.

But it seems that the *transfer* task doesn't wait for the SSH in *clean-remote* to finish first.
Is there a way to wait for the SSH session to complete before proceeding?

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var scp = require('gulp-scp');
var ssh = require('gulp-ssh');

gulp.task('transfer', ['clean-remote'], function () {
    return gulp.src('...')
        .pipe(scp({
            host: '...',
            path: '...'
        })
    );   
})

gulp.task('clean-remote', function () {
    ssh.exec({
        command: ['cd ...', 'rm *.js', 'exit'],
        sshConfig: {
            host: '...'
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: It looks like the `exec` function is not returning a stream or a promise, so you have no way of knowing when the command has finished. I would open an issue on the github repo.

Comment: OK, thanks. Seems like a callback was already an outstanding issue on github. I'm thinking about working with the node ssh2 client directly, and skipping the gulp plugin.

Comment: If that doesn't work for you, you can always use the [`gulp-shell`](https://github.com/sun-zheng-an/gulp-shell) plugin with the normal ssh command string.